# How to optimize a Selenium webdriver crawler?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, optimization

So, I have to crawl a table in each webpage in a website, there are 324 web pages (meaning 324 tables) and each table has 1000 rows and 7 columns, but 1 column is useless and I didn't use that one.

The code is kind of okay but the problem is it's very slow and it takes a lot of time.I was wondering if I could do some changes to the code to make it faster!

Here's the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://beheshtezahra.tehran.ir/Default.aspx?tabid=92')
driver.maximize_window()

part_count = 1
li = []
for i in range(0, 324):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    firstname = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='dnn$ctr1877$DeadSearch$txtname']")))
    lastname = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='dnn$ctr1877$DeadSearch$txtFamily']")))
    part = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='dnn$ctr1877$DeadSearch$txtPart']")))

    firstname.clear()
    firstname.send_keys("%")
    lastname.clear()
    lastname.send_keys("%")
    part.clear()
    part.send_keys(str(part_count))

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr1877_DeadSearch_btnSearch"]').click()

    print('Saving the information..')
    first_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
    last_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[3]')
    fathers_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[4]')
    birth_date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[5]')
    death_date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[6]')
    grave_info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[7]')

    print('Appending the information..')
    for j in range(0, 1000):
        li.append(first_name[j].text)
        li.append(last_name[j].text)
        li.append(fathers_name[j].text)
        li.append(birth_date[j].text)
        li.append(death_date[j].text)
        li.append(grave_info[j].text)

    print('Page ' + str(part_count) + ' is crawled!')
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    part_count += 1
    print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

And in the end, I wrote the list into a CSV file. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: use [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) to narrow down what is causing slow execution time

Answer (score 0):

What you could do after the `print('Saving the information..')` part:

```py
    print('Saving the information..')
    page_snapshot = lxml.html.document_fromstring(driver.page_source)
    first_name = page_snapshot.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
    last_name = page_snapshot.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[3]')
    fathers_name = page_snapshot.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[4]')
    birth_date = page_snapshot.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[5]')
    death_date = page_snapshot.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[6]')
    grave_info = page_snapshot.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[7]')

    print('Appending the information..')
    for j in range(0, 1000):
        li.append(first_name[j].text)
        li.append(last_name[j].text)
        li.append(fathers_name[j].text)
        li.append(birth_date[j].text)
        li.append(death_date[j].text)
        li.append(grave_info[j].text)
```

lxml is blazing fast, just `import lxml.html` (after pip install ofc. :)) and make sure that the page is completely loaded before you grab the snapshot.